# Оставить только цифры и точку в регулярном выражении

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Реализую проверку формы при помощи регулярки. Хочу реализовать удаление всех посторонних символов, кроме цифр, точки и еще раз цифр. Чтоб разрешено было вводить данные типа `99.99999`.

Делаю так:

```
$('body').on('keypress', '#input', function()
{
    var preg = $(this).val().replace(/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]$/i);
    $(this).val(preg);
});
```

В результате у меня удаляются все символы, какие я бы не ввел. Что я делаю не так? Пытался добавить к шаблону `/^[0-9]{0,3}+\.[0-9]{0,5}$/i`, но с добавленными к шаблону значениями регулярка выводит ошибки. А добавил я значения к шаблону для того, чтоб максимальное число можно было вводить `100.00000`.

Comment: Функция replace заменяет (а без второго параметра удаляет) _совпавшую_ по регулярке строку. Следовательно регулярка должна находить то, что не имеет права встречаться в строке. Либо разрешенная часть должна выбираться в групы захвата (`()`) и подставляться вторым параметром replace(//,'$1')

Comment: @Mike ясно, спасибо буду рыть в этом направлении

Comment: @Mike, без второго параметра не удаляет, а заменяет на _undefined_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
$('body').on('keypress', '#input', function() {
  var preg = $(this).val().replace(/[^.\d]+/g,"").replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' );
  $(this).val(preg);
});
```

```js
alert("13142..124.12.4...124..12.4asdf.afsgsfg12451.125dfg12.12.123".replace(/[^.\d]+/g,"").replace( /^([^\.]*\.)|\./g, '$1' ))
```

Comment: Благодарю, отличный пример. Да, вы правы, у вас с 1 точкой работает!

Comment: @N0ob вчера на твой вопрос отвечал с parseFloat

Comment: там немного о другом

Answer (score 1):

Не правильно используется метод [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

1. Не задан второй обязательный параметр, указывающий на что именно заменять
2. не верно регулярное выражение: в шаблоне должно указываться **что** нужно найти и заменить, таким образом в текущем виде регулярка ищет все числа и заменяет их на *undefined*, что является значением по умолчанию второго параметра.

Таким образом надо изменить само выражение

```
/[^\d.]/ig
```

А далее использовать `parseFloat` либо `Number`

```
var preg = $(this).val().replace(/[^\d.]/ig, '');
$(this).val(parseFloat(preg));
```

**Update:** для варианта с несколькими точками можно использовать следующий вариант вызова функции `replace`

```
var preg = $(this).val().replace(/\D/ig,function(){
    var dotCount = 0;
    return function($0){ 
        if($0 == '.' && !dotCount) {
            dotCount += 1;
            return $0;
        }
        return '';
    }  
}());
```

Comment: Благодарю, замечательно работает!

Comment: @N0ob, кстати, возможно не будет работать если в строке несколько точек будет

Comment: Считаю, что мой вариант лучше, он оставляет только первую точку.

Comment: @N0ob не будет работать с несколькими точками

Comment: @N0ob, добавил вариант убирающий лишние точки :-)